# How to club Safe Deployment Transaction and Enable Module Transaction with safe-core-sdk/protocol-kit v2.0.0?

Tags: safe-core-sdk, safe-core

I have been trying to use Safe-core-sdk/protocol-kit v2.0.0.

I am using the `wrapSafeTransactionIntoDeploymentBatch` function to batch the Safe Creation + Enable Module transaction.

I can create the batch transaction data successfully.

But when I execute the transaction , it throws an error saying "Safe is not deployed."

Is it the desired behaviour? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is not the expected behavior - `wrapSafeTransactionIntoDeploymentBatch` should indeed deploy the safe and then execute all transactions batched in.

Maybe you are using relaying services that could interfere with the contract creation? Please share more context on the error so we can look into it more thoroughly.

Hope it helps,
Louis